# ng-if conditions for input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I little bit mixed up in conditions for my ng-if and need some help. I'm rendering form on my page with help ng-repeat and couple custom filters. Check this [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/SccT3wcDIwgN7ymLeDwB?p=preview) up. The thing is I need to provide comboboxes only for three keys from array but placeholder should be with current value of this data. 
This is my div

```
<div ng-repeat="k in rowKeys | filter: '!0' | filter: '!$$'" ng-model="rowVal" >
     <div ng-if="(k === 'id' || k.toLowerCase().endsWith('id') === false) ? true : false">
      <label for="rowValue[{{$index}}]" class="col-sm-2">
       {{k | hide:'.name' | makeUppercase }}:
       </label>
              <div class=" col-sm-2">
       <input ng-if="!isObject(rowData[k])" ng-disabled="disableInput(k)"  class="form-control rowValue" id="rowValue[{{$index}}]"
       ng-model="rowData[k]"/>

       <input ng-if="isObject(rowData[k])"
       ng-disabled="disableInput(k)"   class="form-control rowValue" id="rowValue[{{$index}}]"
       ng-model="rowData[k].name"/>
       <select ng-if="isObject(rowData[k]) && k == 'status'" ng-model="rowData[k].status" class="form-control">
          <option ng-repeat="item in status" value="{{item.value}}">{{item.label}}</option>
           </select>
        <select  ng-if="isObject(rowData[k]) && k == 'priority'" ng-model="rowData[k].priority" class="form-control">
         <option ng-repeat="item in priorities" value="{{item.value}}">{{item.label}}</option>
        </select>
       <select  ng-if="isObject(rowData[k]) && k == 'severity'" ng-model="rowData[k].severity" class="form-control">
      <option ng-repeat="item in severities" value="{{item.value}}">{{item.label}}</option>
      </select>
     </div>
```

as you can see, I have a 3 conditions:

1. Simple key - value
2. Object key - value
3. Object key - value with restrictions by key

So the problem is I can't write expression that to force combobox and input fields work properly. If I'm doing something like this `ng-if="isObject(rowData[k]) && k == 'status'"` the input has disappear at all in any other way I can see them together for one key. Also second problem is that I can't get how to put current value to placeholder in combobox. I appreciate if somebody could help me to figure out where is my mistake.

code:

```
  $scope.load = function(){

  $http({
       method: "GET",
       url: 'test.json'
       })
       .then(function success(response) {
              $scope.rowData = response.data;
                  console.log($scope.rowData)
       }, function error(response) {
                 console.log("It has happend error in response")
  }).then(function(){
      $scope.id = $scope.rowData.id;
            console.log($scope.id);
           $scope.rowKeys = Object.keys($scope.rowData);
  })
  }

  $scope.isObject = function(value) {
    if(angular.isObject(value)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  $scope.disableInput = function (obj) {

         if (obj === 'eventType'){
                return true
            }
         else if (obj === 'id'){
                return true
            }
         else if (obj === 'createdDate'){
                return true
            }
         else if (obj === 'occuredDate'){
                return true
            }
         else if (obj === 'study'){
                return true
            }
  };

  $scope.priorities = [
                { value: 'high', label: 'High' },
                { value: 'medium', label: 'Medium'},
                { value: 'low', label: 'Low'}
            ];
            $scope.severities = [
                { value: 'benign', label: 'Benign' },
                { value: 'severe', label: 'Severe'},
                { value: 'medium', label: 'Medium' },
                { value: 'mild', label: 'Mild'}
            ];
            $scope.status = [
                { value: 'new', label: 'Open' },
                { value: 'closed', label: 'Closed'}
            ];

})
```

Comment: Instead of editing the answer into your question, just answer your own question with your solution.

Comment: @ryanyuyu the main problem wan't resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've beat it by myself. This is working code

```
<div ng-repeat="k in rowKeys | filter: '!0' | filter: '!$$'" ng-model="rowVal" >
    <div ng-if="(k === 'id' || k.toLowerCase().endsWith('id') === false) ? true : false">

        <label for="rowValue[{{$index}}]" class="col-sm-2">

            {{k | hide:'.name' | makeUppercase }}:
        </label>
        <div class=" col-sm-2">
            <input ng-if="!isObject(rowData[k])"
                   ng-disabled="disableInput(k)"
                   class="form-control rowValue"
                   id="rowValue[{{$index}}]"
                   ng-model="rowData[k]"/>

            <input ng-if="isObject(rowData[k]) && k !== 'status' && k !== 'priority' && k !== 'severity' "
                   ng-disabled="disableInput(k)"
                   class="form-control rowValue"
                   id="rowValue[{{$index}}]"
                   ng-model="rowData[k].name"/>

            <select ng-if="isObject(rowData[k]) && k == 'status'"
                    ng-model="rowData[k].name"
                    class="form-control rowValue"
                    id="rowValue[{{$index}}]"
                    ng-options='stat.value as stat.label for stat in status' >
                <option value=''>{{rowData[k].name}}</option>
            </select>
            <select ng-if="isObject(rowData[k]) && k == 'priority'"
                    ng-model="rowData[k].name"
                    class="form-control rowValue"
                    id="rowValue[{{$index}}]"
                    ng-options='prior.value as prior.label for prior in priorities' >
                <option value=''>{{rowData[k].name}}</option>
            </select>
            <select ng-if="isObject(rowData[k]) && k == 'severity'"
                    ng-model="rowData[k].name"
                    class="form-control rowValue"
                    id="rowValue[{{$index}}]"
                    ng-options='sev.value as sev.label for sev in severities' >
                <option value=''>{{rowData[k].name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```